# Error while accessing references from Resource.kt file in Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin

I get below error while trying to access refferences from my Resources.kt file

[image].

Below shows my full code on LoginViewModel.kt

```
package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
): ViewModel() {

    private val _login = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>>()
//        MutableSharedFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>>()
    val login = _login.asSharedFlow()

    fun login(email: String, password: String){

        viewModelScope.launch {
            _login.emit(Resource.Loading())
        }

        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email,password
        ).addOnSuccessListener {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                it.user?.let {
                    _login.emit(Resource.Success(it))
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                _login.emit(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Below shows the Resource.kt file

```
package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.util

sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data:  T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
){
    class Success<T>(data:T):Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message:String):Resource<T>(message = message)
    class Loading <T>: Resource<T>()
    class Unspecified <T>: Resource<T>()

}
```

I have tried to implement using the same way I did for other view models.

I did the same approach to access same variables on RegisterViewModel.kt and it works without any error. Below is the code for that functioning view model

```
package lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.receiveAsFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.data.User
import lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.util.*
import lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.util.Constants.USER_COLLECTION
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth,
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _register = MutableStateFlow<Resource<User>>(Resource.Unspecified())
    val register : Flow<Resource<User>> = _register

    private  val _validation = Channel<RegisterFieldsState>()
    val validation =_validation.receiveAsFlow()


    fun createAccountWithEmailAndPassword(user: User, password: String) {

        if (checkValidation(user, password)){
            runBlocking {
                _register.emit(Resource.Loading())
            }
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                it.user?.let {
                    saveUserInfo(it.uid, user)
//                    _register.value = Resource.Success(it)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                _register.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
            }
    } else
    {
        val registerFieldsState = RegisterFieldsState(
            validateEmail(user.email), validatePassword(password)
        )
        runBlocking {
            _validation.send(registerFieldsState)
        }
    }
    }

    private fun saveUserInfo(userUid: String, user: User) {
        db.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
            .document(userUid)
            .set(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                _register.value = Resource.Success(user)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                _register.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
            }
    }

    private fun checkValidation(
        user: User,
        password: String
    ) : Boolean {
        val emailValidation = validateEmail(user.email)
        val passwordValidation = validatePassword(password)
        val shouldRegister =
            emailValidation is RegisterValidation.Success && passwordValidation is RegisterValidation.Success

        return shouldRegister
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with solving above issue please.Why it gives an error when trying to call Resource.Loading() from LoginViewModel.kt?

Answer (score 0):

Please check import class in LoginViewModel, You are importing

```
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource
```

It should be from this  package `lk.ac.kln.mit.stu.mobileapplicationdevelopment.util`